# Django - Template tags with model instance methods

Tags: python, django

Say I have a template that renders the tag `{{ model.choicenumber }}`, returning an integer of 3. Using the model instance method like `{{ model.get_choicenumber_display }}` will return a human-friendly 'Three' string in this scenario.

I'm looking to mix the [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method and the [|add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#add) template filter so that `{{ model.choicenumber|add:'1' }}` will print 'Four'. Trying something like `{{ model.get_choicenumber|add:'1'_display }}` returns the error

> Could not parse the remainder: '_display' from
>   'model.get_choicenumber|add:'1'_display'

Thanks!

Edit: To clarify; the integer 3 doesn't necessarily equal the string 'Three', but I have just used this comparison for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The template filter `apnumber` from [`django.contrib.humanize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/humanize/#apnumber) will do this for you

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ model.choicenumber|add:'1'|apnumber }}
```

You can add [`capfirst`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#capfirst) if you want the first char to be uppercase

```
{{ model.choicenumber|add:'1'|apnumber|capfirst }}
```

Comment: Apologies but I was looking for something with more flexibility - the integer 3 doesn't necessarily have to equate the string 'Three' but could be any other word (I just used this comparison to simplify the scenario).